# webkit fullscreenchange not firing, webkitendfullscreen not actually when the fullscreen has ended - IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, webkit, fullscreen

I've got an issue in an IOS app where a webview hands of natively to fullscreen but on exit of fullscreen `this.video.webkitEnterFullscreen()` the video does exit but then becomes paused.

I've tried adding a listener for `webkitendfullscreen` which fires fine but i cannot call this.video.play however as there seems to be an animation of around 420ms between the stream exiting fullscreen and floating back to its original position. Ive then tried `fullscreenchange` and `webkitfullscreenchange` but neither of these events fire. I dont want to use a timeout, is there any other way around this?

Thanks in advance,

Sam